# Typhoeus timeout = connection or download?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typhoeus

When I specify the timeout while making a Typhoeus request, is that timeout a connection timeout or download timeout? If it's a connection timeout is there any way to specify a downloading timeout as well?

Example:

```
Typhoeus::Request.new(url, **:timeout  => 3000**, :followlocation => true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It perhaps depends on the version you are using. Since Typhoeus 0.5 it is this: [libcurl timeout](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTTIMEOUT). Which should include the transfer. Compare to [libcurl connect timeout](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTCONNECTTIMEOUT).

Comment: Also, the timeout value is in seconds rather than milliseconds, I assume?

Comment: Actually, I can confirm it's in seconds. Typhoeus documentation really needs to be updated to conform with their API changes!

Comment: Unfortunately the website is outdated - but the rdoc should be up to date.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Typhoeus README has been updated since the original post/answer.

https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus#timeouts

> `timeout` and `connecttimeout`. `timeout` is the time limit for the entire request ***in seconds***. `connecttimeout` is the time limit for just the connection phase, again ***in seconds***.

There are also two more fine-grained option `timeout_ms` and `connecttimeout_ms`, but timeouts in ms are only supported if you compile `curl` with an asynchronous resolver.